# is there anything in qt to handle registering an application?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, registration, qt4.7

I'm writing an app using C++ and the Qt Framework 4.7 to run on Windows, Mac and Linux desktop.  When someone installs or runs my app the frist time, I need to gather some registration information, and return a registration code or something so on subsequent runs, the app knows it has already been registered.

I have not been able to find anything in the Qt Framework that supports this directly.  I'm fairly new to C++ and Qt, so maybe I'm just missing something.

My goal is to collect some information (such as email address so I can notify of updates), and to charge a small fee in order to allow access to all features in the app.

I'm not trying to stop determined hackers, just want normal folks who download, install and run my app to have to register (and pay - maybe that's a separate issue) before they can use some features.  And of course, I want the whole process to be as easy and unobtrusive as possible to the user.

What are the "best practice" options for implementing user registration in my C++/Qt app?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Qt doesn't provide any of this type of functionality. For Mac OS X, you can have Apple take care of most of the registration and payment details by providing your application through the [Mac App Store](http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store/).

For Windows and Linux though, you're mostly on your own.

Comment: thanks...are there any best practice documents for this kind of thing?  free libraries that are normally used?